# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'HTTP Error (60): SSL certificate : self signed certificate in certificate chain'

Tags: php, api, ssl, curl, crm

**UPDATE**

I have seemed to get it working and error does not happen now.

I have used these lines of code in my `php.ini`

```
curl.cainfo="C:/xamp/ca-bundle.crt"
openssl.cafile="C:/xamp/ca-bundle.crt"
```

But question I have now is this safe practice? what are security implications? & how would this reflect on say server/hosted environment?

---

Hi am currently doing some  API call tests in PHP using Insightly CRM system https://github.com/Insightly/insightly-php

I am using XAMPP and am successfully getting data back from the CRM and displaying it in my cmd/console.
I had to do a work around and place the line `curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem"` into my `php.ini` to get it to work in console.

I would like to get it displaying in my `.php` webpage and this error is coming up `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'HTTP Error (60): SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain'`. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Heres my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
    require("insightly.php");
    $i = new Insightly('api key');
    $contacts = $i->getContacts();
?>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>PHP Insightly Test</h1>
<?php
    foreach ($contacts as $contact)
    {
        echo $contact->CONTACT_ID;
        echo " ";
        echo $contact->FIRST_NAME;
        echo " ";
        echo $contact->LAST_NAME;
        echo "\n";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.